# If this is a correct past perfect sentence "As Scheduled , Rahul and I had a discussion over roll off dates"?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to learn past perfect tense as tried one of them as

"As Scheduled , harry and I had a discussion over party".

Is this sentence correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Good news.  Your verb tense is correct (past perfect)
Bad news.  There are other errors.  The capitalization is wrong.  Lowercase "s" for "scheduled" and uppercase "H" for "Harry".  Also, "over party" is not correct.  Did you mean "at the party"?

---

Sorry, I completely messed up here.  Past perfect tense is used to describe that one event happened *before* some other event.  You need the "had" plus past participle to create the proper verb tense.  However, the sentence "As we had scheduled, Harry and I discussed over project dates." is not necessarily past perfect since we do not know if the schedule was made before the project dates were discussed (were you ahead of schedule).
  So, to make this into something past perfect consider the following:
"Harry and I had discussed project dates when they were scheduled."
That is to say, the discussion was done prior to the scheduling, making it past perfect.

Comment: First of all thanks for help, lets rephrase it like , "As scheduled , Harry and I had a discussion over project dates." is that correct ?

Comment: I was curious as per the grammar rules of past perfect tense . "had" event should come before !!

Comment: The other errors are as you say, but the first sentence in this answer is incorrect—there is no past perfect construction in the sentence given at all. The simple past which is used in the sentence is perfectly correct, but there is no past perfect in sight.

Comment: So How i suppose to say this , lets say . "In the past it was discussed or decided that harry and i will discuss on project dates, so we did "

Comment: "As we had scheduled , harry and I discussed over project dates" Is that make sense ?

Comment: Yes, that last one makes sense and uses an actual past perfect construction. The one before it does not work, though; in the past it was decided that you and Harry _should_ or _would_ (but not will) discuss project dates. Note that you have a discussion over/about/on something, but you do not discuss over/about/on something—you just discuss it.